# Transition from one div to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to make animation on my web app. On click, I need to move only ID table column from one div to another div, another column needs to hide. But with animation. I make JSFIDDLE for this, but I can't figure how to do animation for MOVING column ID (from green div) to red div. https://jsfiddle.net/q4eotzb0/6/

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  //This will hide the DIV by default.
  $scope.IsVisible = true;
  $scope.ShowHide = function() {
    //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
    $scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible;
  }
});
```

```
<br />
<br />
<div class="meni col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <ul>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>home</li>
 </ul>
</div >
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

<div class="test col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-class="{'divOpen': IsVisible}">
 <div ng-if="!IsVisible">
    ID<br>
    50<br>
    51<br>
    52<br>
 </div>
 <div ng-if="IsVisible">
  MAPs
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="testtest">
 <input type="button" ng-if="!IsVisible" value="Back" ng-click="ShowHide()" />
   <table class="table" ng-if="IsVisible">
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>LOCATION</td>
    <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>LOCATION</td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="SHOW/HIDE" ng-click="ShowHide()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>LOCATION</td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="SHOW/HIDE" ng-click="ShowHide()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>LOCATION</td>
   INFO item
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.test {
background: red;
width: 50px;
height: 350px;
-webkit-transition: width 2s;-moz-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;-ms-
transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 2s ease-in-out;transition: width 2s;
}


.divOpen{
 width: 100px;
 }
.testtest{
 background: green;
 height: 350px;
 width: auto;
 }
.meni {
 background-color: grey;
 height: 350px;
 }
```

Comment: CSS transitions won't help

Comment: Ok, can you help me with suggestions? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the Angular router was made for! 
You can set a new templateUrl for each route and just have it change on a click, or event.

You will need to link an extra script (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js), an example of how the router looks can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp.

[JSFIDDLE that explains ngRoute fairly well.](https://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/1238/)

Then just basically add the css transition to the incoming html object:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.home.html">
    <h1 class="fade-in"> Home </h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.about.html">
    <h1 class="fade-in"> About </h1>
</script>
```

Comment: I think you don't understand me. I use ui router for change state in my app. There is another thing, in my state i have two div... and I need to animeted move only one table column from table to second div.

Comment: I dont understand what youre trying to do.. but if you just want to "move" an object, css transition it, then hide it using a seperate thread in JS.